# Transaction Usage in CakePHP 2.1.3

Tags: cakephp-2.1

I am using innoDB based Database. How I can use the Transaction to save the data.

I have an array of users. But only saves the last record in the database. I can not use saveAll, because I have to save the data in multiple tables and all of them are interrelated.

I even can not define the model association-ship because there are huge number of entries in my database. So each time join will perform.

Please suggest how I can use the Transaction concept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All transactions are performed on the current DataSource object.

Firstly you need to get it (in the model):

```
$dataSrc = $this->getDataSource();
```

[This method](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/model#method-ModelgetDataSource) returns the DataSource object that is currently bound to the Model.

Then you can use the [DataSource Object's methods](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/data-source) to begin, commit or rollback [transactions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/transactions.html#transactions):

```
$dataSrc->begin();
//Do something 

if (/*Everything is nice?*/) {
    $dataSrc->commit();
} else {
    //Bad things have happened
    $dataSrc->rollback();
}
```

You will have to implement your own logic of course. Since [Cake 2.2 you can also do real nested transactions](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/lorenzo/2012/07/01/cakephp_2_2_and_2_1_4_released). A "nested transaction" according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_transaction) is:

> A nested transaction occurs when a new transaction is started by an
>   instruction that is already inside an existing transaction. The new
>   transaction is said to be nested within the existing transaction,
>   hence the term. Nested transactions are implemented differently in
>   different databases. However, they have in common that the changes are
>   not made visible to any unrelated transactions until the outermost
>   transaction has committed. This means that a commit in an inner
>   transaction does not necessary persist updates to the database.

Of course all this is dependent on the Database you're using. [MySQL InnoDB **transactional** storage engine](http://www.innodb.com/) does support transactions.

And another clarification in response to this comment:

> Yes, I am using $this->Model->saveAll($this->request->data,
>   array('deep' => true) in my controller. This is written under a
>   foreach loop. And only the last foreach record is going to be saved
>   into the database. – Arun Jain

`$this->Model->saveAll();` does NOT need to be run in a loop! It will manage things for you "automagically". Take it out of the loop. 
Furthermore your question was concerning transactions, not saving data with saveAll(). [Model::saveAll()](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/model#method-ModelsaveAll) is just a wrapper for [saveMany()](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/model#method-ModelsaveMany) and [saveAssociated()](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/model#method-ModelsaveAssociated) - it will choose which method to use depending on the type of Model association.

Read the [Cake Book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html) it is all very well explained there...

Comment: when i am trying to use $dataSrc = $this->getDataSource(); it gives me an error: use of undefined method.

Comment: Are you trying to do it anywhere else rather than in a **Model**? There is no other case for you to get the _use of undefined method_ error.

Comment: Yes, I am using $this->Model->saveAll($this->request->data, array('deep' => true) in my controller. This is written under a foreach loop. And only the last foreach record is going to be saved into the database.

Comment: `$this->Model->saveAll();` does NOT need to be run in a loop! It will manage things for you "automagically". Take it out of the loop. Furthermore your question was concerning transactions, not saving data with `saveAll()`. [`Model::saveAll()`](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/model#method-ModelsaveAll) is just a wrapper for  saveMany() and saveAssociated() - it will choose which method to use  depending on the type of Model association. Read the [Cake Book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html) it is all very well explained there...

Comment: Thanks, I know the usage of saveAll() method. But what my case is, I have to save the data for multiple users with number of entries needs to be saved into users associated tables. And according to some conditions those associations may changing dynamically for each user.

Comment: Well you can't pass a data array for all users at once and be able to save it. You should pass the array in the appropriate manner for each user. If you want to change the Model associations on the fly you should use model bindings as they are dynamic and can be changed any time with `$this->ModelName->bindModel();` and `$this->ModelName->unbindModel();`